# Android Using @hide methods via reflection

Tags: android

Apart from the risk of the hidden api being changed by Android developers in the future, which seem to an obvious risk you take if you use hidden api, what are other downsides of using it? especially, I would like to know if there is any legal aspect? should I declare anything on the manifest? It doesn't seem to enforce anything... I googled around, didn't find anything on the legal side.

Thanx,
O.

Answer (score 0):

You might also face issues with differences between device vendors. It did happen in the past.

Comment: Thanx, I will make the required tests.